# Apache Lucene - Optimizing Searching

Tags: java, spring, apache, lucene

I am developing a web application in Java (using Spring) that uses a SQL Server database. I use Apache Lucene to implement a search feature for my web application. With Apache Lucene, before I perform a search I create an index of titles. I do this by first obtaining a list of all titles from the database. Then I loop through the list of titles and add each one of them to the index. This happens every time a user searches for something.

I would like to know if there is a better, more efficient way of creating the index? I know my way is very inefficient, and will take a long time to complete when the list of titles is very long.

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you create a new index each time instead of storing it? You can update it from time to time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before you optimize Lucene: SQL Server already has a [full-text search](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx) feature. If this covers your use case then use it. It's the easiest way since SQL Server takes care of keeping the search index in sync with the database.

If the SQL Server full-text search does not fit your use case then your application has to create its own search index and keep it in sync with the database. To do this you should:

- create / update the search index when your application starts
- update the search index when the application inserts, updates or deletes a title

Lucene is flexible where it stores the search index. You can store it in a directory in your file system or in the database (or write you own storage provider). I recommend to store it in the file system as the performance is much better than when you store it in the database.

If you don't have too many titles to index you could also use an in-memory search index which you recreate every time your application starts.

Comment: I think I'm going to stick with Lucene and use the solution you provided. Thanks

Comment: I'm sort of a noob with Lucene, so can you please suggest a tutorial for saving an index on a file system and then loading it up?

Comment: [Lucene in 5 minutes](http://www.lucenetutorial.com/lucene-in-5-minutes.html) is a good starting point. Just replace `RAMDirectory` with `FSDirectory` in the tutorial and Lucene will save the index in a file.

Answer (score 0):

You should:

1. make Lucene index before you start application
2. update index when you add/remove/update title in your database

Benefits of this approach:

1. One full index when application is offline
2. incremental indexing, each time relevant information is changed

Comment: Thanks, this seems simple enough for me to understand and implement.