# Apache Lucene - Creating and Storing an Index?

Tags: java, apache, spring-mvc, lucene

This post if a follow-on from my previous question:
[Apache Lucene - Optimizing Searching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21229469/apache-lucene-optimizing-searching/21229549?noredirect=1#comment31980053_21229549)

I want to create an index from title stored in my database, store the index on the server from which I am running my web application, and have that index available to all users who are using the search feature on the web application.

I will update the index when a new title is added, edited or deleted.

I cannot find a tutorial to do this in Apache Lucene, so can anyone help me code this in Java (using Spring).

Comment: which lucene version are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my understanding to your question, you need to do the following :

1) Index you data (titles in your case)
first you need to implement the code that create that index for you data, check this sample of code.

```
Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_CURRENT);

// Store the index in memory:
//Directory directory = new RAMDirectory();

Store an index on disk
Directory directory = FSDirectory.open(indexfilesDirPathOnYourServer);
IndexWriterConfig config = new IndexWriterConfig(Version.LUCENE_CURRENT, analyzer);
IndexWriter iwriter = new IndexWriter(directory, config);
Document doc = new Document();
String title = getTitle();
doc.add(new Field("fieldname", text, TextField.TYPE_STORED));
iwriter.addDocument(doc);
iwriter.close();
```

here you need to loop over you all data.

2) Search for you indexed data.
you can search for you data by using this code:

```
DirectoryReader ireader = DirectoryReader.open(indexfilesDirPathOnYourServer);
IndexSearcher isearcher = new IndexSearcher(ireader);
// Parse a simple query that searches for "text":
QueryParser parser = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_CURRENT, "fieldname", analyzer);//note here we used the same analyzer object
Query query = parser.parse("test");//test is am example for a search query
ScoreDoc[] hits = isearcher.search(query, null, 1000).scoreDocs;
// Iterate through the results:
for (int i = 0; i < hits.length; i++) {
  Document hitDoc = isearcher.doc(hits[i].doc);
  System.out.println(hitDoc.get("fieldname"));
}
ireader.close();
directory.close();
```

Note : here you don't have to fetch all the data from your DB, you can directly get it from index. also you don't have to re-create the whole index each time user search or fetch the data, you can update the title from time to time when you add/update or delete one by one (the title that have been updated or deleted not the whole indexed titles).

to update index use :

```
Term keyTerm = new Term(KEY_FIELD, KEY_VALUE);
iwriter.updateDocument(keyTerm, updatedFields);
```

to delete index use :

```
Term keyTerm = new Term(KEY_FIELD, KEY_VALUE);
iwriter.deleteDocuments(keyTerm);
```

Hope that help you.

Comment: This helped a lot. I managed to get my search working efficiently. Thanks a lot.